# Why does TypeScript claim it "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature"?

Tags: typescript

**edit**: as requested, TypeScript version is 3.2.2

There are plenty of questions and answers regarding this specific error on StackOverflow but none of them satisfactorily explain **why** this happens.

In my understanding, if I have a type like:

```
type Something = number[] | string[]
```

Then `Something` can either be an array of numbers or any array of strings. Regardless of the contents of the array, it should have properties like `filter` and `map`. But if I use this type in a function:

```
function doSomething(s: Something): void {
  s.map()
}
```

Then the `cannot invoke an expression....` error is thrown.

This is easily fixed by changing `Something` to:

```
type Something = (number | string)[]
```

Now TypeScript will not complain about call signatures but I do not understand why. For all intents and purposes, `(number | string)[]` and `number[] | string[]` seem identical to me. It can be an array containing numbers, or it can be an array containing strings. Call signatures don't seem to even be relevant when defining types like this.

The docs even say:

> A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. We use the vertical bar (|) to separate each type, so number | string | boolean is the type of a value that can be a number, a string, or a boolean.

And:

> If a value has the type A | B, we only know for certain that it has members that both A and B have.

So even from what I read in the official docs, `number[] | string[]` and `(number | string)[]` should behave identically.

Is this a bug? Am I missing the point or just otherwise being overly dense? I know this seems irrelevant to most but I'm really trying to understand this so I hope someone can provide a decent explanation.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294) seems related

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the TypeScript team [just wrote about improvements to calling methods on union objects](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types) a few days ago with the release of TypeScript 3.3. The [main PR implementing the improvement](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/29011) also has helpful context. The TypeScript team also has [written about why it's a tricky problem to solve  in a recent language design meeting](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29033).

---

In brief though, when first designing calling methods on union types, the TypeScript team initially "erred on the safe side much of the time to say that signatures had to be identical" in order for a method to be callable.

The recent changes in TypeScript 3.3 have improved the situation somewhat, and method calls on unions now work when their arguments share a common type, for example:

```
type Fruit = "apple" | "orange";
type Color = "red" | "orange";

type FruitEater = (fruit: Fruit) => number;     // eats and ranks the fruit
type ColorConsumer = (color: Color) => string;  // consumes and describes the colors

declare let f: FruitEater | ColorConsumer;

f("orange"); // It works! Returns a 'number | string'.
```

However, even with this new fix:

> This new behavior only kicks in when at most one type in the union has multiple overloads, and at most one type in the union has a generic signature. That means methods on `number[] | string[]` like `map` (which is generic) still won't be callable.

Essentially, it's just a quite complicated issue for the TypeScript team to implement reasonably, and they haven't fully worked out the best solution yet. It's fair to say though that the current behavior isn't the way things are *supposed* to work, so you could call it a bug if you wished.

Comment: That was enlightening and I really appreciate you sharing it. In the PR, he mentions "with more infrastructure, this is potentially fixable", I'm wondering if you might know what he means by that? Either way, this answered my question and then some, I guess I'll ignore this behavior for now

Comment: I think he's saying that the pre-existing code for handling types of this nature in the TypeScript codebase isn't developed enough yet to make handing the issue in question easily. I don't know what specifically lacking though.